# Start script with Popen

Tags: python

I have the following pythons script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import datetime
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import pifacedigitalio
from time import sleep
pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital() # creates a PiFace Digital object
testprocess = None
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if ((now.hour >= 6 and now.minute >=30) and (now.hour < 9)) or ((now.hour >= 7) and (now.hour < 10)):
     if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
         subprocess.Popen(["/bin/led/aus"])
         sleep(5)
         testprocess = Popen(["/bin/led/Zone1-4Morgen"])
         sleep(1)

if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 0:
    if testprocess:
        testprocess.kill()
        testprocess = None
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/led/aus"])
        sleep(1)
```

The script is not exactly doing what I want, maybe you can help. Within time window and `pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1` it should switch off /bin/led/aus and start script /bin/led/Zone1-4Abend.

If input `pfd.input_pins[0].value` returns to 0, it should kill the script
Zone1-4Abend and switch off /bin/led/aus.

Below script works ok, all I did in the above script was to add a time window. So the script only continues if time window and `pfd.input_pins[0].value` is true.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import pifacedigitalio
from time import sleep
pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital() # creates a PiFace Digital object
testprocess = None

while(True):
    if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:

        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/led/aus"])
        sleep(5)
        testprocess = Popen(["/bin/led/Zone1-4Morgen"])
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: "*The scrip is not exactly doing what I want*" - OK, so what is it doing?  By the way, you are not waiting for the first `Popen` to complete before starting the next, could that be a problem?

Comment: when a start the scrip in command line it runs only untlil  "print (True)" the rest I can not see.

Comment: Until print (True) it is ok, afterwards, not even /bin/led/aus starts

Comment: If you `print(True)` then `testprocess` will be `None`, i.e. False, so `"/bin/led/aus"` will not be run.

Comment: I delete the, else: statEment.  see above)  Stil, "/bin/led/aus" does not execute.

Comment: So, did you print your conditions?  Obviously if it is not executing the code then your `if` conditions are False, so check `pfd.input_pins[0].value` at least.

Comment: I edited my script in the first post again. I took the print off, and I check, the time window  is ok and the if condition is 1. still not working. before  I removed print(True) it showed condition True

Comment: now = datetime.datetime.now() I think you are instantuating DateTime wrong... https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/

Comment: ...plus (now.hour >= 6 and now.minute >=30) and (now.hour < 9) doesn't mean after 0630... it means for every minute greater than 30 after 0600.

Comment: thanks for the info. how would then the correct code be for a window between 6.30h and 10.00h and why is afterwords the  "/bin/led/aus" not exeuted??

Comment: anybody has a solution why  "/bin/led/aus" will not execute??

Comment: @cdarke removed print(True) else: print(False) Problem still the same.

Comment: Did you display `pfd.input_pins[0].value` as I suggested?

Comment: @cdark , yes, I can simulate "pfd.input_pins[0].value", if it is  1 and not in the time window it prints False, if "pfd.input_pins[0].value" is 0 and not in the time window it prints False. It only prints True if "pfd.input_pins[0].value" is 1 and in time window, so this works correct, it is the  just below, the /bin/led/aus is not executed. I updated my first post, the second script which does exactly the same works ok, just does not have this time window.

Comment: if window_ok and ((now.hour >=16 and now.minute >=30) and (now.hour <23)) or ((now.hour >=22) and (now.hour <23)):
    if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/led/aus"])
        sleep(5)
        testprocess = Popen(["/bin/led/Zone1-4Abend"])
        sleep(1)

        if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 0 :
            if testprocess:
                testprocess.kill()
                testprocess = None
                subprocess.Popen(["/bin/led/aus"])
                sleep(1)